# Integer in rules for parser definition - Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, ocamlyacc

I am running into a problem when compiling the following rule for my parser:

%%

expr:

```
  | expr ASN expr { Asn ($1, $2) }
```

This is an assignment rule that takes an integer, then the assignment (equal sign) and an expression, as defined in my AST:

type expr =
     Asn of int * expr

Of course, the compiler is complaining because I am defining "**expr** ASN expr", and the first argument should be an integer, not an expression. However, I have not been able to figure out the syntax to specify this.

If somebody could lead me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what you want is the assignment as:

```
type expr = Asn of var * int
```

and then define expr in the parser as:

```
expr:
  | VAR ASN INT { Asn ($1, $2) }
```

in the lexer you should have defined VAR as string and INT as integer literal too, just as examples:

```
| [a-zA-z]+ { VAR($1) }
| [0-9]+ as i { INT(int_of_string i) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't supply enough details to give a good answer. What do you mean by an integer? I'll assume you mean an integer literal.

Assuming your lexical definitions have a token named INT that represents an integer literal, you might want something like this.

```
expr:
    | INT ASN expr { Asn ($1, $2) }
```